# Cloud load failed with error code 7 using Unity GoolePlayGames plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I get the following log during on-device debugging

**Error:**

```
*** [Play Games Plugin DLL]  ERROR: Cloud load failed with status code 7
```

Basically the `OnStateLoaded()` callback function always returns the boolean `success = false` and I can't figure out the reason why.

All that the plugin debugging logs mention is "Cloud load failed with status code 7".

Answer (score 1):

According to the android doc, 7 is a  generic "developer error", see https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateStatusCodes.html#STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR

I tried a quick sample and everything worked ok.  Here are my steps:

1. Created a new game in the play console
   (https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
2. Made sure Saved Games is set
   to ON
3. Linked an Android Application Remembering the application ID
   (the number after the title) and the package ID
4. Created a new project in Unity
5. Added the play games plugin (Assets/Import Package.../Custom
   Package)
6. Set the application ID (Google Play Games/Android Setup...)
7. Switched the platform to Android (File/Build Settings...)
8. Set the player settings (bundle identifier and the keystore info)
9. Added a new script component to the camera
10. Saved everything and hit build and run.

    Here are the contents:

    ```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using GooglePlayGames;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using System;

    public class SaveSample : MonoBehaviour {

    System.Action<bool> mAuthCallback;
    GameData slot0;


    void Start () {
        slot0 = new GameData(0,"waiting for login....");
        mAuthCallback = (bool success) => { 
            if (success) {
                Debug.Log("Authentication was successful!");
                slot0.Data  =" loading....";
                slot0.LoadState();
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Authentication failed!");
            }
         };

         // make Play Games the default social implementation
         PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

         // enable debug logs 
         PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

         //Login explicitly for this sample, usually this would be silent
         PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(mAuthCallback, false);         
    }

    protected void OnGUI() {

        Screen.fullScreen = true;
        int buttonHeight = Screen.height / 20;
        int buttonWidth = Screen.width / 5;  
        GUI.skin.label.fontSize = 60;
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = 60;

        Rect statusRect = new Rect(10,20,Screen.width,100);
        Rect dataRect  = new Rect( 10, 150, Screen.width,100);
        Rect b1Rect = new Rect(10, 400, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect b2Rect = new Rect(b1Rect.x + 20 + buttonWidth,
                               b1Rect.y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        if(!Social.localUser.authenticated) {
            if(GUI.Button(b1Rect, "Signin")) {
                Social.localUser.Authenticate(mAuthCallback);
            }
        }
        else {
            // logged in, so show the load button and the contents of the saved data.
            if(GUI.Button(b1Rect, "Load")) {
                slot0.LoadState();
            }
            GUI.Label(dataRect, slot0.Data);
        }

        if(GUI.Button(b2Rect, "Save")) {
            // just save a string, incrementing the number on the end.
            int idx = slot0.Data.IndexOf("_");
            if (idx > 0) {
                int val = Convert.ToInt32(slot0.Data.Substring(idx+1));
                val++;
                slot0.Data = "Save_" + val;
            }
            else {
                slot0.Data = "Save_0";
            }
            slot0.SaveState();
        }

        GUI.Label(statusRect, slot0.State);
    }

    // Class to handle save/load callbacks.
    public class GameData : OnStateLoadedListener {

        int slot;
        string data;
        string state;

        public GameData(int slot, string data) {
            this.slot = slot;
            this.data = data;
            this.state = "Initialized, modified";

        }

        public void LoadState() {
            this.state += ", loading";
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).LoadState(0, this);
        }

        public void SaveState() {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            this.state += ", saving";
            ((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).UpdateState(slot, bytes, this);
            }

        public void OnStateLoaded(bool success, int slot, byte[] data) {
            if (success) {
                Debug.Log ("Save game slot : " + slot + " loaded: " + data);
                if (data != null) {
                    char[] chars = new char[data.Length / sizeof(char)];
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, chars, 0, data.Length);
                    this.data = new string(chars);
                        this.state = "loaded";
                } else {
                        Debug.Log ("Saved data is null");
                        this.data = "";
                        this.state = "loaded, but empty";
                }
            } else {
                // handle failure
                Debug.LogWarning ("Save game slot : " + slot + " failed!: ");
                this.data = "";
                this.state = "loading failed!";
            }
        }

        public byte[] OnStateConflict(int slot, byte[] local, byte[] server) {
            // resolve conflict and return a byte[] representing the
            // resolved state.
            Debug.LogWarning("Conflict in saved data!");

            state = "conflicted";
            // merge or resolve using app specific logic, here
            byte[] resolved =  local.Length > server.Length ? local : server;
            char[] chars = new char[resolved.Length / sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(resolved, 0, chars, 0, resolved.Length);
            this.data = new string(chars);

            return resolved;
         }

         public void OnStateSaved(bool success, int slot) {
             Debug.Log ("Save game slot : " + slot + " success: " + success);
             state = "saved";
         }

         public string Data {
             get {
                return data;
             }

             set {
                data = value;
                state += ", modified";
             }

         }

         public int Slot {
             get {
                return slot;
             }

         }

         public string State {
            get {
                return state;
            }
         }
    }
    ```

    }

Comment: Does the constant value given in the documentation equate to status code? Didn't figure that!

Comment: Also cloud save seems to be working for me. Can cloud save work in spite of failed license check?

Comment: Could also be a generic "developer error", see https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateStatusCodes.html#STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Comment: Getting kindof confusing. How can I debug if I'm not even sure about the cause?

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for testing this out for me. I tried your code in my project today and guess what, exactly the same thing is happening as with my code. Saving works fine but loading fails! This is so weird, what on earth could I have done wrong??

Comment: UPDATE : tried implementing your code in a new unity project. Still  loading does not work! :-|

Comment: After some more research, this is affect of deprecating the appstate API, so new games cannot save using this api any longer.  Stay tuned, there is an update to the plugin coming, which will support the Saved Games API.  You can read more about the depreciation at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6136246?rd=1

Comment: Ignore this answer, my other answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 7 is because the Cloud Save API has been deprecated and is only currently accessible to existing games that have used the API.  The Unity plugin version 0.9.11 has been updated to use the SavedGames API.

I tried a quick sample and everything worked ok. Here are my steps:

1. Created a new game in the play console
   (https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
2. Made sure Saved Games is set to ON
3. Linked an Android Application Remembering the application ID
       (the number after the title) and the package ID Created a new
       project in Unity
4. Added the play games plugin (Assets/Import
       Package.../Custom Package)
5. Set the application ID (Google Play
       Games/Android Setup...)
6. Switched the platform to Android (File/Build
       Settings...)
7. Set the player settings (bundle identifier and the
       keystore info)
8. Added a new script component to the camera Saved
       everything and hit build and run.

Here is my script:
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using GooglePlayGames;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using System;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SavedGame;

```
public class SaveSample : MonoBehaviour {


    System.Action<bool> mAuthCallback;

    GameData slot0;

    bool mSaving;
    private Texture2D mScreenImage;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        slot0 = new GameData("New game");
        mAuthCallback = (bool success) => {

            if (success) {
                Debug.Log("Authentication was successful!");
                slot0.State = "Click load or save";
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Authentication failed!");
            }

      };


        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .EnableSavedGames()
            .Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

        // Activate the Play Games platform. This will make it the default
        // implementation of Social.Active
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        // enable debug logs (note: we do this because this is a sample; on your production
        // app, you probably don't want this turned on by default, as it will fill the user's
        // logs with debug info).
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

        //Login explicitly for this sample, usually this would be silent
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(mAuthCallback, false);


    }

    public void CaptureScreenshot() {
        mScreenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        mScreenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        mScreenImage.Apply();
    }

    protected virtual void OnGUI() {

        Screen.fullScreen = true;

        int buttonHeight = Screen.height / 20;
        int buttonWidth = Screen.width / 5;

        GUI.skin.label.fontSize = 60;
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = 60;


        Rect statusRect = new Rect(10,20,Screen.width,200);
        Rect dataRect  = new Rect( 10, 250, Screen.width,100);

        Rect b1Rect = new Rect(10, 800, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        Rect b2Rect = new Rect(b1Rect.x + 20 + buttonWidth, b1Rect.y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

        if(!Social.localUser.authenticated) {
            if(GUI.Button(b1Rect, "Signin")) {
                Social.localUser.Authenticate(mAuthCallback);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(GUI.Button(b1Rect, "Load")) {
                mSaving = false;
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ShowSelectSavedGameUI("Select game to load",
                                                                                   4,false,false,SavedGameSelected);
            }

            GUI.Label(dataRect, slot0.Data);
        }

        if(GUI.Button(b2Rect, "Save")) {
            int idx = slot0.Data.IndexOf("_");
            if (idx > 0) {
                int val = Convert.ToInt32(slot0.Data.Substring(idx+1));
                val++;
                slot0.Data = "Save_" + val;
            }
            else {
                slot0.Data = "Save_0";
            }
            mSaving = true;
            CaptureScreenshot();
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ShowSelectSavedGameUI("Save game progress",
                                                                               4,true,true,SavedGameSelected);
        }

        GUI.Label(statusRect, slot0.State);

    }


    public void SavedGameSelected(SelectUIStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {

        if (status == SelectUIStatus.SavedGameSelected) {
            string filename = game.Filename;
            Debug.Log("opening saved game:  " + game);
            if(mSaving && (filename == null || filename.Length == 0)) {
                filename = "save" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
            }
            if (mSaving) {
                slot0.State = "Saving to " + filename;
            }
            else {
                slot0.State = "Loading from " + filename;
            }
            //open the data.
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(filename,
                                                                                             DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                                                                                             ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,
                                                                                             SavedGameOpened);
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error selecting save game: " + status);
        }

    }

    public void SavedGameOpened(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
        if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {
            if( mSaving) {
                slot0.State = "Opened, now writing";
                byte[] pngData = (mScreenImage!=null) ?mScreenImage.EncodeToPNG():null;
                Debug.Log("Saving to " + game);
                byte[] data = slot0.ToBytes();
                TimeSpan playedTime = slot0.TotalPlayingTime;
                SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder builder =  new 
                    SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder()
                        .WithUpdatedPlayedTime(playedTime)
                        .WithUpdatedDescription("Saved Game at " + DateTime.Now);

                if (pngData != null) {
                    Debug.Log("Save image of len " + pngData.Length);
                    builder = builder.WithUpdatedPngCoverImage(pngData);
                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log ("No image avail");
                }
                SavedGameMetadataUpdate updatedMetadata  = builder.Build();
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.CommitUpdate(game,updatedMetadata,data,SavedGameWritten);
            } else {
                slot0.State = "Opened, reading...";
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(game,SavedGameLoaded);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error opening game: " + status);
        }
    }

    public void SavedGameLoaded(SavedGameRequestStatus status, byte[] data) {
        if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {
            Debug.Log("SaveGameLoaded, success=" + status);
            slot0 = GameData.FromBytes(data);
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error reading game: " + status);
        }
    }


    public void SavedGameWritten(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
        if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {
            Debug.Log ("Game " + game.Description + " written");
            slot0.State = "Saved!";
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning("Error saving game: " + status);
        }
    }


    public class GameData  {

        private TimeSpan mPlayingTime;
        private DateTime mLoadedTime;
        string mData;
        string mState;

        static readonly string HEADER = "GDv1";

        public GameData(string data) {

            mData = data;
            mState = "Initialized, modified";
            mPlayingTime = new TimeSpan();
            mLoadedTime = DateTime.Now;

        }

        public TimeSpan TotalPlayingTime {
            get {
                TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now.Subtract(mLoadedTime);
                return mPlayingTime.Add(delta);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString () {
            string s = HEADER + ":" + mData;
            s += ":" + TotalPlayingTime.TotalMilliseconds;
            return s;
        }

        public byte[] ToBytes() {
            return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(ToString());
        }


        public static GameData FromBytes (byte[] bytes) {
            return FromString(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(bytes));
        }

        public static GameData FromString (string s) {
            GameData gd = new GameData("initializing from string");
            string[] p = s.Split(new char[] { ':' });
            if (!p[0].StartsWith(HEADER)) {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to parse game data from: " + s);
                return gd;
            }
            gd.mData = p[1];
            double val = Double.Parse(p[2]);
            gd.mPlayingTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(val>0f?val:0f);

            gd.mLoadedTime = DateTime.Now;
            gd.mState = "Loaded successfully";
            return gd;
        }

        public string Data {
            get {
                return mData;
            }

            set {
                mData = value;
                mState += ", modified";
            }

        }

        public string State {
            get {
                return mState;
            }

            set {
                mState = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```